# Grafana login with oauth2_proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, oauth-2.0, grafana, oauth2-proxy

**Issue:**

I am trying to set up a very simple configuration locally

- `grafana` running on default port `3000`
- `oauth2_proxy` running on default port `4180`

**Expectation**:

Expectation is: after successfully login through `oauth2_proxy` using google credentials, the login "is carried over" in Grafana. However, the user is only redirected to the Grafana login page.

Steps to reproduce:
Create the following empty directory structure

- `/monitoring`

  - `/data/grafana` // this acts as mounted volume to grafana
  - `/data/oauth2`  // this acts as mounted volume to oauth2_proxy

Copy the `docker-compose.yaml` file below, inside the `/monitoring` folder

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    user: '104'
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      # [users]
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
      - GF_USERS_AUTO_ASSIGN_ORG=true
      - GF_USERS_AUTO_ASSIGN_ORG_ROLE=Admin

      # [auth]      
      - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true

      # [auth.generic_oauth]
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_NAME=OAuth
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=true
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=<google_client_id>
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=<google_client_secret>
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_SCOPES=openid email nickname
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_AUTH_URL=http://localhost:4180/auth
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL=http://localhost:4180/token
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_API_URL=http://localhost:4180/userinfo

  oauth2-proxy:
    container_name: oauth2-proxy
    image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4180:4180
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data/oauth2:/var/lib/oauth2_proxy
    environment:
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER=oidc
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID=<google_client_id>
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET=<google_client_secret>
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_OIDC_ISSUER_URL=https://accounts.google.com
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET=<some_secret>
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_DOMAIN=http://localhost:3000
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS=*
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:3000/oauth2/callback
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS=http://:4180
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAMS=http://localhost:3000/
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECURE=false
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_ERRORS_TO_INFO_LOG=true
```

run

`docker-compose up -d --build`

Run Grafana:
`http://localhost:3000`

[image]

So far so good, we get Grafana login page with only OAuth login enabled

Now we click on OAuth login button

[image]

After successful authentication, the user authenticated session is not carried over to Grafana. Instead, the user is redirected to login page.

No errors in either Grafana or oauth2_proxy

Please note, using Google as Identity Provider here is only for simplification (I am aware that I can plug that in directly in grafana without oauth2_proxy) The reason I am using generic_oauth is because, ultimately, the oauth2_proxy will be integrated with a corporate identity provider.

Comment: You don't need any oauth2-proxy. I guess you find it somewhere, but that's a solution for old Grafana version, which didn't have OIDC support - a few years ago. Now, Grafana has good native support for OIDC, so just configure all GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_* properly.

Comment: I've configured the last 3 grafana env variables to point to the Google OAuth2 params, but it still doesn't work. 
```
 - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_AUTH_URL=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
      - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_API_URL=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/userinfo
```
Redirect url is the oauth login origin url, which in my case is http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth (this is grafana's, not something I am configuring)

This is not compliant with Google policies

Comment: See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/generic-oauth/ and note about root_url

Comment: @JanGaraj many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In fact your first suggestion was enough. I think I just hit a bug in grafana (or maybe it's "as designed")
The issue I had with missmatch_url is caused when you naviate to login page directly: http://localhost:3000/login. If you instead go to http://localhost:3000 , which will automatically redirect you to http://localhost:3000/login (provided you don't have the auth cookie), then it works from the get go.

Comment: @JanGaraj If you add your first comment as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @JanGaraj, I have posted somewhat a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73090668/grafana-running-behind-nginx-and-authenticated-through-oauth2-proxy. Any idea what I might be doing wrong this time around? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any oauth2-proxy. I guess you find it somewhere, but that's a solution for old Grafana version, which didn't have OIDC support - a few years ago. Now, Grafana has good native support for OIDC, so just configure all GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_* variables properly.